# How can I prove that this two statements are equivalent?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

Given: complete graph G and I a list assignment for G
prove:
G has proper coloring $\Leftrightarrow $
$ \forall \;Z\subseteq V(G)$ : $\mid Z \mid \leq  \mid \cup_{z\in Z}\; I(z)  \mid $

Can someone give me a hint how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an auxiliary bipartite graph $H$ defined as follows. One of partite set of $H$ is the set $V=V(G)$ of vertices of $G$ and the other is the set $C=\cup_{z\in V} I(z)$ of all given colors. An edge between a vertex $z\in V$ and a color $c$ exists, if $c\in I(z)$. A matching $\mathcal M$ on $H$ is called *$V$-saturating* provided each vertex of $V$ belongs to an edge from $\mathcal M$.  There exists a natural bijection $f=\{(v,c(v)):v\in V\}$  between proper colorings $c$ of $G$ and $V$-saturating matchings on $H$. So $G$ has a proper coloring iff there exists a $V$-saturating matching on $H$. By [Hall marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) this holds iff $$ \forall \;Z\subseteq V : |Z|=|N_H(Z)|= \left| \bigcup_{z\in Z}\; I(z)  \right|.$$